# Is a wife allowed to stop going to the mikva?

Tags: halacha, marriage, sexuality, mikvah-ritual-bath

If a wife no longer wants to have relations with her husband, is it allowed for her to stop going to the mikva, in order to prevent relations?

Comment: is it allowed for her to stay in the marriage? that's question 1.

Comment: "stop going to the mikva, in order to prevent relations"? I think a more reasonable course of action for her would be "refuse relations" and possibly "stop going to the mikva, because there's no real point". Another fairly reasonable course of action would be "keep going to the mikva, to avoid _harchakos_" and "refuse relations". Why would she need to "stop going to the mikva, in order to prevent relations"?

Comment: (Sorry if it seems like I'm breathing down your throat. I don't mean to, and you're certainly very welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. I'm just confused about the question.)

Comment: @msh210 To reduce immediate pressure from the husband and/or reduce the risk of marital rape and/or as a power play.

Comment: @DoubleAA and here's one more tragic one -- I'd heard about a husband who would beat his wife, but only when she wasn't a nidda -- because he'd never touch a nidda!

Answer (score 8):

A woman who prevents her husband from having relations with herself, is a מורדת - and this is grounds for divorce.

Details can be found in the Rambam - [הלכות אישות - Ch 14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/4114.htm) (Halachot 10 - 15) and in Shulchan-Aruch Even-HaEzer  Ch. 154:3-6 (למי שכופין להוציא בגט)

Comment: But is it allowed? Sounds like she might not mind divorce.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree, needs further clarification. I edited in the source. The Rambam extends Moredet to a niddah, even, so it would seem that he addresses this specifically, though I would imagine he has in mind a woman who is actually bleeding or counting clean days (see law 13). I actually up voted, but withdrew mine, then downvoted and withdrew! I think the tendency for many users who sorta skim is to think either "huh! this is useful" or "meh...", vote, and move on

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Avigdor Miller writes in his shalom bayis manual, Career of Happiness, that a wife should never cease going to the mikvah because of marital difficulties. However, I'm not sure if it's permitted halachically.

Comment: It sounds like it's not. What else would "should never" mean? Is it guidance to prevent worsening an already bad situation?

Comment: @SethJ Yes, from the tapes of R' Miller that I've heard, he does not sound like he is stating a *p'sak* but rather guiding the parties how to get out of difficult situations.